# Why evaluates "IS NULL" in SSMS interactive mode to "TRUE" but the same statement being executed in a SP to "FALSE"?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

**Given**

```
DECLARE @IN__CUST_NO    INT
DECLARE @OUT__USER_ID   INT
SET @IN__CUST_NO = 1000006660
```

**CASE 1: *IS NULL* evaluates *TRUE***

Since no `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` with the value of `1000006660` exists in our dummy `USERS`-Table, stating a `SELECT` restricting to tuples of `CUSTOMER_NUMBER`-Columnvalues of `1000006660` leads to a zero-sized resultset. Hence `IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE` in following statement issued to SSMS interactivly; resulting to `PRINT 'null'`

```
SELECT @OUT__USER_ID = u.ID
FROM USERS u 
WHERE u.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = @IN__CUST_NO

IF (@OUT__USER_ID IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'null'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'set'
END
```

**CASE 2: *IS NULL* evaluates *FALSE***

As above no `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` with the value of `1000006660` exists. But if one encapsulates the `IS NULL` part in a stored procedure like below and executes it, `IS NULL` will result to `FALSE`! (at least on my configuration; using SQL-Server 2005 and SSMS 2008). Endresult: `PRINT 'set'`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NULL_TEST
    @IN__CUST_NO        INT,
    @OUT__USER_ID       INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @OUT__USER_ID = u.ID
    FROM USERS u 
    WHERE u.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = @IN__CUST_NO

    IF (@OUT__USER_ID IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'null'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'set'
    END
END

EXEC SP_NULL_TEST @IN__CUST_NO, @OUT__USER_ID=@OUT__USER_ID
```

Please, can someone explain this strange behaviour? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested this using `CREATE TABLE USERS (ID INT, CUSTOMER_NUMBER INT);` then your code and I get 'null' in both cases.

Comment: When no rows exist `@OUT__USER_ID` retains its previous value rather than being set explicitly to `NULL`. Sure in your test code you aren't assigning a value to the variable before doing the `EXEC` version?

Comment: I've made a test script with your info but all the time I get: NULL, NULL... Are you sure you're not missing something :-)?

Comment: Initializing `@OUT__USER_ID` with `NULL` solved the problem; @Martin

Comment: @Jack Douglas: to accept Erik's answer would be unfair to Martin Smith because he had answered the question as a comment two and a half weeks before Erik posted his answer (see above)

Comment: I don't think @Martin will mind - or you could suggest he posts his comment as an answer. The important thing is for Googlers to be sure they've found what they are looking for without having to read a comment thread.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `@OUT__USER_ID` with `NULL`, since it is probably being set to a non-null value earlier in your script somewhere.